# How to access sharepoint intranet from internet?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a static internet website and like to have SharePoint intranet link for employees only which should connect intranet from outside of the network. How to acheive this? In other words, Is there any way to access SharePoint intranet from outside of the network? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

it's called "Extranet";

1. Create A-record in your DNS for your domain name for what you want that points to your public IP address. We generally use team.companyname.com
2. Set your firewall to port forward Port 80 to your internal server running SharePoint
3. In Alternate Access Mappings under the SharePoint Central admin control panel change the site to the match the A-record you created.

   - Its under Application Management
   - Alernate Access Mappings, you can leave the type at Default.
4. If there is anything you want secured I'd look at SSL and moving to port 443.